How compute correlation between images
I try to compute correlation between classes. The dataset involves several folders which are named by class. Each folder includes several images, I have used the below code to input images and labeling it with several classes
#  Specify root path
   root_path = './Datasets_1'
   name_class = os.listdir(root_path)
   dataset_Path = list(glob.glob(root_path+'/**/*.*'))
   labels = list(map(lambda x : os.path.split(os.path.split(x)[0])[1],dataset_Path))
   dataset_Path = pd.Series(dataset_Path,name = 'FilePath').astype(str)
   labels = pd.Series(labels,name='Label')
   data = pd.concat([dataset_Path,labels],axis =1)
   data = data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop= True)

So how to compute correlation between these classes??

Your question is quite a long way from being a [mcve]... no data, no import statements, no expected/actual results.

Could you give several images as an example? You can use dhash to compute similarity between two images. Will it work for you? Or alternatively SIFT.

To explain more, in slandered data we uses method such as heatmap to calculate correlation such as this example

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
clf.fit(x, y)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.bar(range(x.shape[1]), clf.feature_importances_)
plt.xticks(range(x.shape[1]),rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Features')
plt.ylabel('Importance')
plt.show

correlation = df.select_dtypes(exclude = 'object').corr()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
sns.heatmap(correlation > 0.8, annot = True, square = True)
